# mysqli_connect not working on MAMP

Tags: mysqli, prepared-statement, mamp

The code below worked on my old iMac with MAMP.  However, it does not work on my new iMac.  How do I fix this?  Do I need to do something to the `php.ini` file?

```
<?php
$dbConnection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx", "gallery");
$query = "SELECT * FROM images";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbConnection,$query);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $categories,$img_name);
   while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
     echo $id."<br />";

 }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable php_mysqli extension in PHP.ini. It's disabled by default.

look for the following line: `extension=php_mysqli`

Answer (score 1):

I grappled with this one for most of a day before the following on the (localhost) MAMP home page caught my eye: if you're running a PHP version 5.5.x or earlier, mysqli_connect() should work fine, but if you're using PHP version 5.6.x or later, try mysqli_init() and see if that works for you. It worked for me! It displays under the heading "Examples". Good luck!